# Youtube api not pausing onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am lazy loading youtube videos using their api when a button is clicked a modal will open up with the video. I am trying to end(not pause) the video when the x button is clicked and when anywhere else on the page is clicked excluding the modal.

I couldnt get the code to format here so I uploaded the code and an example to a domain I dont use.
http://erebosquotes.com/example1.html

I expected the video to pause when the button is clicked and the modal closes. I have not attempted to have the video pause when clicking outside the modal.

Comment: I can see you use `javascript` to create a `iframe` of the youtube video but I don't see you loading in the youtube player `API` which is why you have no control over the events of that video/player.

Comment: If someone manually clicks the play image button is there no way to stop the video?

Comment: If you load the player `API` you can control all player events such as: **play** - **pause** - **stop** - **seek** - **next** - **previous** - **volume**

Comment: You could just remove the iframe from the DOM when a user clicks the "x". You don't even need to tap into the API with all the more you're doing. Just add the iframe embed when needed and remove it when closed. iframe src parameters can give you autoplay among many other options.

Comment: I am sorry I am kinda newbie to javascript how do I go about doing that. also by loading the api player does that take more resources.

Comment: @BSK But the OP is asking how to pause the video if the window is closed assuming it should resume play from the pause if re-opened... removing the iframe or replacing it isn't going to do that.

Comment: @CarlosO'gorman Just to be clear... You say you want to pause the video if closed... why? Are you wanting that video to resume from the last play point if re-opened because if not then you don't need to pause it, you only want to stop it. Please try explain your expectations from this and I might be able to be of further assistance.

Comment: @NewToJS I was thinking what you just said but removing the iframe wouldnt be the worst as long as a new one is created when the button is clicked gain

Comment: I guess pausing was the wrong word I meant stopping the video all together

Comment: @NewToJS Yes, you are correct. The OP did not specify that so I'm not assuming anything. If we are making assumptions then it would also be fair to assume that what I mentioned would work for their solution.

Comment: @CarlosO'gorman So you only want one player that will play - pause/stop and play a new video... you can do this using iframes as **BSK** has suggested but using the player `API` you can use one iframe/player and change the source/events rather than removing/replacing them over and over. The advantages only depend on the amount of videos - loading - expectations of your project. Since you are using what appears to be lightbox I would go with the `API` and change the player source on selection and stop the player when closed.

Comment: actually I just read the part about the light box I would rather go with the api @NewToJS

Comment: @NewToJS How would I go about changing the source and stop the player when closed

Comment: @CarlosO'gorman I think I understand what you are wanting maybe the examples I have might be of some use to you? If so let me know so I can explain how it works which you might learn from and will know how to add/edit if required for future purposes. [**Coded4u Demo**](https://coded4u.com/erebosquotes) - [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/ejvLbt7d/)

Comment: @NewToJS thank you so much omg I have tried so long to get this to work

Comment: You are very welcome, I hope you understand the source code in the demo I have provided. If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: @NewToJS please consider move your comment as an answer and so, the OP will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I have been meaning to do that but have been very busy. I will be sure to turn my comment into a answer once I get the time to do that. This could take a little more time than a normal answer as it will require a small explanation of each step which this has many and I would like to be sure I provide the relevant documentation to each description without turning my post into a tutorial. Thank you for the reminder **Mauricio Arias Olave** much appreciated.

Comment: you welcome, @NewToJS and have a nice day :)